# How to iterate through multidimensional JSON data and pass the corresponding values to a function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I have this JSON data

```
settings{
   "logo_dark":"logo_dark.png",
   "logo_light":"logo_light.jpg",
   "favicon":"favicon.png",
   "hero_logo":"hero_logo.jpg",
   "name":"Anime Stock",
   "short_name":"AnimeStock",
   "desc":"Description",
   "keywords":"keywords"
}
```

How can i call a function to loop through all the values and return data depending on which arguments i pass to the function. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
getSiteSettings(logo_dark); // logo_dark.png
```

Here's what i've tried

```
getSiteSettings: (state) => (item) => {
        const settings = state.siteSettings
        for (const setting in settings) {
            if (settings.hasOwnProperty(setting)) {
                const element = settings[setting].item;
                return element;   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: just updated. Please check

Comment: *"multi dimensional"* ... where? I see a `settings` object with a list of properties all with primitive values, i.e. there's no other dimension

Comment: `getSiteSettings: (state) => (item) =>` - you do realise that `getSiteSettings` is a function that returns a function? and if it was not, then calling it with `logo_dark` (incorrect) is not the same as calling it with `"logo_dark"` (correct)

Comment: There are other arrays below this one

Comment: also, your (invalid) JSON seems to have a `settings` property, which you reference in your attempt as `siteSettings` ... first, you need to show what your JSON actually is, as what you've shown is not JSON, then you may be able to get an answer

Comment: @SkykidFelix - there are *no arrays* so saying there are *other arrays* just confused the issue - and it's still not JSON - so, please, show the JSON - or is it simply a javscript object and there's no JSON involved at all?

Comment: `settings[logo_dark]`?

Answer (score 1):

It's bit difficult to understand what you need to do. But depend on your output, I can provide a this kind of answer.

```js
var settings = {
   "logo_dark":"logo_dark.png",
   "logo_light":"logo_light.jpg",
   "favicon":"favicon.png",
   "hero_logo":"hero_logo.jpg",
   "name":"Anime Stock",
   "short_name":"AnimeStock",
   "desc":"Description",
   "keywords":"keywords"
};

function getSiteSettings(val){

    for(var key in settings)
        if(key === val)
            return settings[key];

}

console.log(getSiteSettings("logo_dark"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of properties, then you can `filter` array if there is `some` property in an object:

```
const result = Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([k, v]) => props.some(s=> s == k))
    .map(([k, v])=> v);
```

An example:

```js
let settings = {
   "logo_dark":"logo_dark.png",
   "logo_light":"logo_light.jpg",
   "favicon":"favicon.png",
   "hero_logo":"hero_logo.jpg",
   "name":"Anime Stock",
   "short_name":"AnimeStock",
   "desc":"Description",
   "keywords":"keywords"
};

const getByProperties = (obj, props) => {
    return Object.entries(obj)
        .filter(([k, v]) => props.some(s=> s == k))
        .map(([k, v])=> v);
}

console.log(getByProperties(settings, ['logo_dark', 'logo_light','favicon']));
```